# Python + Selenium click form button in the overlay

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

Hi I am trying to automate a report download from website. I am struck at clicking export csv button which appears when I click on export button.

My code-

The below code successfully opens the overlay (as shown in image on the right side)

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button').click()
```

Now I want to download the csv from this overlay below are my trials both fail.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[9]/div/div/div/div/div/form[1]/button"))).click()
# driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/div/div/div/div/div/form[1]/button').click()
```

Form element -

```
<form target="_blank" method="post" action="/report/export/v2/" class="export-csv"><button type="submit" class="Button__ButtonBlank-sc-1wnez5l-2 ExportButton__MenuButton-c8rp21-0 cJAgdC">Export CSV</button><input type="hidden" name="query" value="{&quot;facets&quot;}}"></form>
```

Button element-

```
<button type="submit" class="Button__ButtonBlank-sc-1wnez5l-2 ExportButton__MenuButton-c8rp21-0 cJAgdC">Export CSV</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason you are using absolute xpath here ? As can not say its right or wrong as for that we need complete page DOM. Also please share DOM instead of image of it.

Comment: @rahulrai updated with the elements

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:** Opening Overlay in a new tab and performing action

```
export = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button')
export_url = export.get_attribute("href")

#Open a new Tab
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
driver.get(export_url)
#Click on export csv botton
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Export CSV']"))).click()
#Close the tab
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'w')
```

Also, make sure switch to frames if its opening in a new iframe.

Comment: hi Rahul it fails with a timeout exception. I looked for iframe but that is not the case. will try to share DOM in the question

Comment: Then only thing left to try is if its opening in a new window. I have updated Answer with switch to window and try. Please try and let me know if it works or still hit any issue.

Comment: just to know, when I do this process manually and click on the Export CSV it does open a new window. So what difference does it make in this context? Also I cannot see the update with a switch to window

Comment: Opening of window after clicking Export CSV button should not have any earing on issue at hand. As i believe issue is clicking Export CSV itself. Please try updated code.

Comment: to confirm in second line do you mean
Export.get_attribute("href") instead of elem.get_attribute("href")

Comment: the problem is href missing from the element we selected. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you print print(driver.window_handles) after clicking Export link and see how many windows are there. Please keep a wait for 7-8 seconds after clicking and before printing.